# Is Paul's sister in Acts 23:16 his biological sister?

Tags: paul, new-testament

> Now the son of **Paul’s sister** heard of their ambush, so he went and
>   entered the barracks and told Paul.
>
> Acts 23:16 (ESV)

### Is Paul's sister in Acts 23:16 his biological sister?

If so,then, the significance of this record links with Acts 16:31 ("Believe on the Lord Jesus and you will be saved, you and your household") since it has shown us that Paul had his relatives saved just as he was.

Comment: Just because Paul's sister cares for his life, it does not follow that she is saved. Furthermore, even if she is saved, it is not necessarily simply because she is Paul's sister.